# Disable audio recording notification while application is in background on iOS SDK 4.2+

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, pjsip

In my project, where we use [pjsip2](http://www.pjsip.org/) to receive streaming audio from a shared server.

The app is meant to only receive streaming audio, not record.
However even though we have disabled the mic in out code we still get a notification of the app recording while it is in the background (top bar flashing red with text: " (recording)").

How can I disable the recording notification while our app is running in the background?

Comment: What have you set in to info.plist for UIBackgroundModes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the audio option from info plist for UIBackgroundModes

Example:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <string>voip</string>
```

Comment: Ty for your answer, tried it, still go the same problem tho.
Have this in my .plist:
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
  <string>audio</string>
 </array>
I'm thinking I still need "audio" as the app plays audio and should be able to do it in the background too.

Comment: if you have voip you will be able to have the current call in bg, but you will to have the red top bar.

Comment: Guessing I won't get around the flashing bar if I need audio in the background.