# Hide Audio Red bar when recording in background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is there a way to hide the red bar when audio recording in background ?

i tried adding  (key>UIBackgroundModes voip) in plist as it is mentioned in a previous post . but my app crashed . Is there another way  ?

Comment: what kind of crash did your app crash with?  what "previous post" are you referring to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456563/disable-audio-recording-notification-while-application-is-in-background-on-ios-s                      Never mind. it was a typing mistake. didn't notice it at first.

Comment: ah, so you're not having a problem anymore?

Comment: I fixed the code that caused my app to crash . And it is recording in background. But the top red bar when its is recording in background remains even when i add the lines from the post to plist.. Is there a wait to remove it ?  .

Comment: @George "mentioned in a previous post" please where?